# page numbering with braces and lines

Tags: vertical-alignment, fancyhdr, rules

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyfoot[C]{ \hrulefill \{ \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage} \} \hrulefill }
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

However, my horizontal line is not vertically centered around page numbering. How can   I fix it?

Comment: Well, my answer is completely useless now -- waste of time :-(

Comment: not actually... it gave me insights in `\hrulefill` command :)

Comment: Well, you distracted users here with your wrongly formulated question, changing it afterwards because you forgot the most important feature of your request. This is annoying, in my point of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)'s headers/footers are set inside boxes and are set from `L`eft to `R`ight. You could set a vertically-centred `\rule` as part of your `L`eft footer, and overwrite this in the `C`enter footer with your regular footer that has a white background:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor,lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\rule[.5ex]{\textwidth}{.4pt}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\colorbox{white}{\{ \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage} \}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The gap between the line and the surrounding braces `\{`..`\}` is given by `\fboxsep` (default is 3pt). This can be changed.

If you'd rather avoid overlaying coloured boxes, you can move the `{ X of Y }` construction down to the baseline level of `\hrulefill`, while additionally reducing `\footskip`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\hrulefill\raisebox{-.5ex}[0pt][0pt]{\{ \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage} \}}\hrulefill}
\setlength{\footskip}{\dimexpr\footskip-.5ex}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```